Homeomorphism of $[0,1]^m$ with subspaces of $S^n$
I was reading the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, which states that there is no continuous map $f$ from $S^2$ to $S^1$ which satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$. One question came to my mind:
Is there any subspace of $S^n$ homeomorphic with $[0,1]^m$, where $m>n>0$?
I think the answer is negative. I tried to prove it by the homeomorphism between $S^n$ with $[0,1]^n/\partial ([0,1]^n)$. But I am not sure.
Does anyone know what to do?!

The answer is indeed negative. Assume $f\colon [0, 1]^m \to S^n$ is an embedding. Restricting the domain of $f$ to $(0, 1)^m$, we obtain an embedding $f'\colon (0, 1)^m \to S^n$ with domain an $m$-manifold, so invariance of dimension tells us that $f'((0, 1)^m) \subset S^n$ must be an $m$-submanifold of $S^n$, which is impossible as we assumed $m > n$.
